# Random - Выбрать случайное число из набора | Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Знаю как сделать рандом из последовательности чисел. Например, с 1 до 4.

```
Random.Range(1, 5);
```

Но не знаю, как сделать рандом из определённых чисел. Например, из чисел: 1, 5, 8, 14. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Как я понял, вам нужно выбрать случайно число из массива чисел. Это можно сделать так:

```
var array = new int[] { 1, 5, 8, 14 };
var randomElement = array[Random.Range(0, array.Length)];
```

Comment: Гениально! Спасибо!